# Global snippet manager that can be plugged in to multiple code editors

Tags: windows, web-development, source-code

I'm looking for a 'global' snippet manager (for CSS, PHP, MySQL, HTML & JavaScript) which has the capability of being accessed by multiple different code editors - such as Notepad++, phpDesigner & Dreamweaver.

So for example you can add a code snippet in Dreamweaver, and it will be available in phpDesigner & Notepad++ for example, and vice-versa.

Does anything like this even exist?